# Generic ArrayList quicksort method - Java

Tags: java, sorting, generics, arraylist, quicksort

I'm currently working on creating a generic ArrayList quicksort method but I'm struggling with making sure all of the types are correct. The line I'm getting an error on is the one that says, "int pivot = arr[pivotIndex];" The error message is in the code next to it. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void quicksort(ArrayList<T> arr, int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end) {
        return;
    }

    int pivotIndex = new Random().nextInt(end - start) + start;
    int pivot = arr[pivotIndex]; // The type of the expression must be an array type but
                                 // it resolved to ArrayList<T>
    swap(arr, pivotIndex, end);

    int leftPointer = partition(arr, start, end, pivot); // the partition method is a
                                                         // helper method that partitions the input.
                                                         // It takes in parameters of ArrayList<T>,
                                                         // int, int, int

    quicksort(arr, start, leftPointer - 1);
    quicksort(arr, leftPointer + 1, end);
}
```

Comment: arr is an ArrayList. Try arr.get(int index)

Comment: Khanna111 is correct, but note that you will still get an error on that line after making the change.  `arr` is an arraylist of type `T`, so the `get()` method will return an element of type `T`, so `pivot` needs to be type `T`.  Then you need to double-check your logic to make sure it still makes sense if `pivot` is of type `T`.